two numbers in title caption when using kable_styling - bookdown - Rmarkdown
I have this Rmarkdown document:
---
title: "xxx"
author: "xxx"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(pacman)

p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(kableExtra)
p_load(knitr)
```

# Introduction


* Number of replicates: $r= 4$
* Number of groups (or factor levels): 3 (35min, 40min, 45min)
* Number of runs: $n=12$

Next we present the code for a possible randomization of this experiment:
```{r }
###makes Randomization reproducible
set.seed(7638)
f <- factor( rep( c("35min", "40min", "45min" ), each = 4))
fac <- sample( f, 12 )
eu <- 1:12
plan <- data.frame( loaf=eu, time=fac ,height=NA)
# uncomment and run only to export to a csv file
#write.csv( plan, file = "Plan.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```
```{r breadRandForm, echo=FALSE}
kable(plan[order(plan$time),],caption="Randomization form",row.names =F) %>% 
kable_styling("striped", position = "center",full_width = F)
```

The caption for the table is being rendered as "Table 1.1: Table 1.2: Randomization form". If I don't use the kable_styling, like so:
```{r breadRandForm, echo=FALSE}
###see http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html
# res<-kable(plan[order(plan$time),],caption="Randomization form",row.names =F)
# kable_styling(res,"striped", position = "center",full_width = F)
kable(plan[order(plan$time),],caption="Randomization form",row.names =F) 
```

The caption is rendered correctly: "Table 1.1: Randomization form".
I am using R version 4.4.1, this is an old code that wasn't behaving like that previously. What can I do to keep using kable_styling and fix the double numbering in the caption?

Use kbl(), not kable().
